# to reset the value when disabling the textbox

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two inputs in which I am applying typeahead:-

```
<div class="form-group>
      <label class="control-label=">Product Code:</label>
         <input placeholder="Enter Value" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.productCode" typeahead="code for code in getProductByCode($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingCodes" typeahead-no-results="noResults"/>

   <label class="control-label">Product Name:</label>
      <input placeholder="Enter Value" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="getNgModel(a)" typeahead="code for code in getProductNameByCode($viewValue,a.producrCode)" typeahead-loading="loadingCodes" typeahead-no-results="noResults" ng-disabled="!a.productCode"/>

   <button type="button" ng-disabled="!a.productCode">Show</button>
  </div>
```

My DIRECTIVE CODE:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('products', products);

    products.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout', 'ApiServices'];

    function products($http, $timeout, ApiServices) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {

            },

            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
              scope.a = {};

              scope.getNgModel = function (a) {
              if(a.productCode){
                return a.productName;
              }else{
                return '';
              }
           };

           scope.getProductCode = function(key){
                var obj = {"key": key}
                if(key.length>=2){
                    return ApiServices.getProductCodee(obj).then(function             (response) {
                        return response.data.map(function(item){
                            return item;
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        scope.getProductCodeByName = function (key,Code) {
            var obj = {"key": key, "Code":Code}
            if(key.length>=2){
                return ApiServices.getProductCodeByName(obj).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data.map(function(item){
                        return item;
                    });
                });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }; 

        },
            templateUrl: ''
        };
    }

})();
```

What I want here is when I select a particular value from product code only then the product name and button gets enabled otherwise disabled. Also when the productName is disabled back the value inside it is set to null.Because the previous value remains bind to it and even disabled.

Comment: in getProductCode function, you can set `a.productName` to `NULL`. So every-time productCode changes, it will reset productName to Null.

Comment: instead of applying on function can I do it somewhere else. Even when I apply it to directive like this scope.a.productCode = null; it is not working.

Comment: inside function is best i think, still you can try adding watch on productCode and if it is null, make productName null.

Comment: @shreyagupta where did you use this `products` directive?? and if you dont mind can I solve this is some different way??

Comment: sure you can solve it in a different method @Saurabh

Comment: any updates on it @Saurabh Agrawal

Comment: Hi @shreyagupta can you share `getProductByCode` and `getProductNameByCode`..

Comment: @shreyagupta I have edited my answer. check that :)

Comment: @shreyagupta did it work for you??

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal the disable part is working but the second part of my question is not can u look at that too

Comment: @shreyagupta As mentioned earlier I am not able to understand the second part of your question.
can you please elaborate it??

Comment: For the second part, when I select product code and then product name and press button 'show' one of my function is called.

Comment: For the second part, My 'product name' and 'show' button gets enabled when I select a particular product code. Then I put values in 'product name' and when I click the 'show' button certain function is called. When I remove that selected value from 'product code', 'button' and 'product code' gets disabled back but the previous value inside the product name remains there. What I want is as soon as it gets disabled the value inside the product name is set to 'null'.

Comment: Ok, Will try to implement it too. Once I get some time, till that you can contact me on my mail. You can get that from my github account. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139540/discussion-between-saurabh-agrawal-and-shreya-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to clearly understand the second part of your question..  *Also when the productName is disabled back the value inside it is set to null.Because the previous value remains bind to it and even disabled*

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.selected = '';
   $scope.states = [
   {
    id:1,
    name:'A'
   },{
    id:2,
    name:'B'
   }
   ];
   var selectedByUser = false;

   $scope.onSelectValue = function(selected){
    $scope.selected = selected.name;
    $scope.disableFields = false;
    selectedByUser = true;


   };

   $scope.changingInput = function(inputValue){
    // $scope.selected = null;
    if (inputValue && inputValue.id) {
     $scope.disableFields = true;
    }else{
     if (inputValue.length>0 && selectedByUser) {
      $scope.disableFields = false;
     }else{
      $scope.disableFields = true;
      // $scope.selected = null;
      selectedByUser = false;
     }
    }

   };

   $scope.disableFields = true;


  });
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label=">Product Code:</label>
   <input placeholder="Enter Value" ng-change="changingInput(selected)" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state as state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="onSelectValue(selected)" typeahead-loading="loadingCodes" typeahead-no-results="noResults"/>

   <label class="control-label">Product Name:</label>
   <input placeholder="Enter Value" type="text" class="form-control" typeahead-loading="loadingCodes" typeahead-no-results="noResults" ng-disabled="disableFields"/>

   <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-disabled="disableFields">Show</button>
  </div>
  {{selected}}

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If it does not work here then copy paste it in your editor and then try. Even after that it does not work then you can go to my [gihub account](https://github.com/sorb999), you will find my email address, then share me your mail address so I will mail you zipped solution.

Comment: I don't  want to use ng-show here. What I want is when the product code is empty then product name is disabled also the value inside the product name is set to null

Comment: ng-model="getNgModel(a)" is a non-assignable expression @Saurabh

Comment: wait I will create a fiddle for it

Comment: @shreyagupta can you post your `array` or json??

Comment: which array or JSON u talking about?

Comment: @shreyagupta can you post a fiddle with issue?? Or some more code.